# How to access NSMutableDictionary when the key looks like an int?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm learning objective-c.

I tried to grab the entry of this `NSMutableDictionary` by using numbers as the key:

```
// [game analysisData] returns the Dictionary

NSMutableDictionary *data = [game analysisData];
NSLog(@"Data:\n%@", data);

// Try using "1" as the key.
id move = [data objectForKey:"1"];
NSLog(@"Move:\n%@", move);
```

But bad output:

`move == (null)`.

So I can't access it with the string `"1"`. Using an `int` doesn't work (compilation error).

Do you know how I can access the entries of this NSMutableDictionary?

Here's what the `description` looks like in FLEXTool:
[image: NSMUTABLEDICTIONARY]

Comment: Seems to be `NSNumber`, but what about having: `for (id aKey in [data allKeys]) { NSLog(@"Key %@ is of class %@", aKey, NSStringFromClass([aKey class])); }` to check that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NSNumber instead. You can write it like this :

```
NSNumber * key1 = @1;
NSNumber * key2 = @(1 + 1);
int intKey      = 3;
NSNumber * key3 = @(intKey);
```

You can also do it with a string like this :

```
id move = [data objectForKey:@"1"]; // you forgot the @
```